# create templates using ggplot2 syntax?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if it's possible to create a similar set of figures in ggplot2 and just change the data somehow. For instance, I can create a function to accomplish this task:

```
plot1 <- function(data) ggplot(data) + geom_line(aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()
plot1(data)
plot1(newdata)
```

But is it possible to save and reuse a set of components in some manner like this? (obviously this does not work):

```
g <- geom_line(aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()
ggplot(data) + g
ggplot(newdata) + g
```

Comment: You could put it as a function, `template = function(d)  ggplot(d) + geom_line(aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()`, though I agree I've been disappointed when I couldn't save components in the way you try here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are the `+.gg` methods described [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/gg-add.html)

These are 
`%+%` and `%+replace%`  which will update / replace elements in `ggplot`s and `themes`

eg

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x =wt, y = mpg,colour = hp)) + geom_point()

# change the variable mapped to y
p %+% aes(y = am)
# change the data set
p %+% mtcars[1:10,]
```

Or you can combine the elements as a list

eg

```
#
g <- list(geom_line(aes(x,y)),theme_bw())
ggplot(data) + g
```

Comment: I thought it would be `p + aes()`, `%+%` being only for data